# How to enable Contracts in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, code-contracts

I tried to include contracts into my project, something like:

```
    public Segment Bounds() {
        Contract.Ensures(segments.Length > 0, "Segments are not empty");
        return new Segment(segments[0].a, segments.Last().b);
    }
```

I get error (shown as message box) which said me that I should install CCRewrite. I got it 
[here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RiSEResearchinSoftwareEngineering.CodeContractsforNET), installed but "Contracts" tab in project settings was not appeared and I continue to get the same error. I'm using Visual Studio 2017 Community. Is it possible to use contracts with this version of Visual Studio?

Comment: Oh, excuse me, free version. Yes, Community

Comment: There is sentence "You must download and run the Code Contracts .msi file. It installs in any edition of Visual Studio other than the Express edition." on download page, so I suspected that contracts are not supported in the community version, only in the paid versions

Comment: What kind of framework/runtime? .NET Framework? Core? Standard?

Comment: .Net Framework 4.7.1 on Windows 10.

Comment: Then AFAIK it should work, but don't know what you should check.

Comment: But does it supported in FREE version too (not only in paid versions?)

Comment: " It installs in any edition of Visual Studio other than the Express edition." on download page" - You answered your own question, no it is not supported in the free version

Comment: I find "Note: Code contracts don’t work for the Visual Studio Express editions but do work with the Free Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition." in https://www.dotnetcurry.com/csharp/1172/code-contracts-csharp-static-runtime-checks, but also issue with DbC in VS2017 https://github.com/Microsoft/CodeContracts/issues/476, so seems it must work but there is an issue :(

Comment: There is a good background info on why taking a dependency on contracts is a bad idea in [this github page](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/24681).  Most relevant quote: "The project is abandoned and all but officially discontinued."

Comment: Express is not the same as Community. If it really installs in anything but Express, then it should install in Community.

Answer (score 1):

From the CodeContract project [wiki](https://github.com/Microsoft/CodeContracts/wiki/Building):

> Visual Studio 2013 is the only version that is supported as a build environment for Code Contracts.

As pointed out in OP's comment, more background information can be found in the following [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/CodeContracts/issues/476):

> I have the same issue, I bet on CC for some largish projects. As much as I love it and will miss it, I think everyone should seriously consider getting them out of their code base sooner rather than later. There is just not enough commitment there from either MS or the volunteers here (I don't blame them, it was always made clear that it's a non supported technology).
>   -- chrisaut

My conclusion (in accordance with @HansPassant's comment) is that the project is abandoned.